# Is there a matrix calculus rule for this?

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, matrix-calculus, karush-kuhn-tucker

My lecture notes differentiate a Lagrangian function.
[lecture notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6IWi.png)

They say the derivative of $\mu^T(Ax-b)$ where $A$ is a matrix and $\mu , x$ are vectors is $A^T \mu$, but I don't understand why it isn't $\mu^TA$. We haven't previously studied any matrix calculus rules before or how to differentiate matrices so I just wanted to see if there is a rule/reason for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: $\mu^T A$ is a transpose vector. If you are  calculating the derivative of a scalar $\phi=\mu^T(Ax-b)$ w.r.t. a vector the result should be a vector; so you need to take the transpose of  $\mu^T A$ which is $A^T \mu$.

Comment: @TedBlack I'm not sure I agree with "the derivative of a scalar wrt a vector should be a vector". It makes more sense for it to be a covector, so a row vector if "vector" means column vector.

Comment: @ronno unfortunately there is a lot of confusion moving between linear algebra and tensor analysis. You are right that $d\phi=D_i dx^i$ where $\phi$ is a scalar and $x^i$ is a vector; $D_i$ is definitely a covector. But then consider trying to interpret the expression $\partial \phi / \partial \mathbf{x}$; if $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector  one interpretation of $\partial / \partial \mathbf{x}$ is a column vector operator. That's the only reason I can see for people choosing to write this derivative as $A^T\mu$ instead of $\mu^TA$.

Answer (score -1):

$\mu^TA$ is just $(A^T\mu)^T$ and for your purposes you need add $n \times 1$  sized vectors instead of $1\times n$